# Compile failed - gwt maven

Tags: maven, gwt, gxt

HTTP ERROR 404

> Problem accessing /WEB-INF/error/error.jsp. Reason: 
>       /WEB-INF/error/error.jsp

```
Caused by:
Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:933)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:757)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:382)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:472)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:511)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:295)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can see the error, when you enable apache logs (as it is written in the error message)

You need to change the log level for "org.apache.jasper" to "error" and add a console appender, then the JSP compiler errors appears in the Java console window, as desired.

For example, paste this into log4j.xml, assuming you have an appender named "console"

```
<logger name="org.apache.jasper">  
     <level value="error"/>
     <appender-ref ref="console"/>
</logger>
```

**A possible problem could be that your Jetty version is not compatible with your java version**

Here you have compatibility list

- Jetty 9, Servlet 3.1, Java 1.8
- Jetty 8, Servlet 3.0, Java 1.6
- Jetty 7, Servlet 2.5, Java 1.5
- Jetty 6, Servlet 2.5, Java 1.4

Comment: Thanks Lorenz, it worked. I was pointing to java 1.7 with jetty 8.x, but no issues with logger